# ASP.NET - sending mail form different domain than SMTP credentials?

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, mailmessage

When sending email using MailClient, is it possible to have the .From property be for an email of a different domain than the credentials passed to the SMTP server? E.g., my credentials passed in are @mydomain.com, but the .From email is @anotherdomain.com. Or, must they be the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify anything you want as the From address!  However it might make it more likely that your message winds up in spam or blocked by a spam firewall.